Summarising by subcategories
Here is anonymised example of my "df" dataset:
structure(list(date = structure(c(19653, 19572, 19572, 19572, 
19572, 19572, 19752), class = "Date"), var_1 = c("def", "jkl", "abc", 
"abc", "ghi", "abc", "ghi), subcategory = c(7, 8, 2, 4, 9, 9, 3), category = c("A", 
"B", "B", "B", "C", "F", "G), location = c("a", "j", "j", "c", "h", 
"h", "d"), time = c("07:30:00", "00:30:00", "00:30:00", "01:30:00", 
"03:40:00", "03:30:00", "07:00:00"), month = c(10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8), year = c(2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

I used lubridate to convert the times into seconds and then used jpsmith's answer:
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(time = seconds(lubridate::hms(time)))

df %>% 
  mutate(total = seconds_to_period(sum(seconds(lubridate::hms(time)))), 
         .by = category) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = subcategory, 
              values_from = time,
              names_prefix = "time_",
              values_fn = lubridate::hms) %>%
  select(order(colnames(.))) # cosmetic, just to reorder column names


but that threw this error:

Error in pivot_wider():
! Applying values_fn to time must result in a single summary value per key.
ℹ Applying values_fn resulted in a vector of length 2.
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

What I would like is a tibble that looks something like this:
# A tibble: 3 × 4
   category             time_2     time_3     time_4      total
   <chr>               <Period>    <Period>   <Period>   <Period>
 1 A                   1H  0M 0S      NA      2H 30M 0S   3H 30M 0S               
 2 B                      NA       1H 30M 0S  0H 30M 0S   2H 0M 0S                       
 3 C                      NA       1H 0M 0S       NA      1H 0M 0S

In an ideal world it would be written in such a way that I could get metrics other than sums out of it, but at this point I just need something that works.

group_by(category, subcat) and then pivot_wider.

Hi, thank you for answering so fast! (I'm not entirely sure if/how you fixed the table issue but thank you for that too if applicable lol). I think I have managed to use your reply to get closer to my goal, I think it's my fault for using such minimal example data, but I'm going to ETA the main post bc I'm running out of characters.

user25005226 you have a lot of text here that is too rambling and unfocused; most people wont read through it. Will you please edit your question to simply include: (1) sample data of what you have, (2) the desired data output, and (3) what you have tried? This will likely get you much better, faster help. Just trying to help you get the support you need here!

jpsmith I appreciate what you're saying, but I can't include sample data - if you know how I can give stackoverflow a bunch of time data that would be a big help. I will try to go through and edit it to be more coherent in a while when I have time. I'm not quite sure what you want me to do re: desired data output?

I think you misunderstood, I’m just suggesting you shorten your question to only include those three things, not that you haven’t already included those. Most of the text in your question is irrelevant. You’ll probably get higher-quality help if you streamline your question in that manner. Again, just trying to help

This should work and provide you with the correct formatted data. First you calculate the total time by category then pivot_wider, using the values_fn to ensure it is in the period format you want.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(total = seconds_to_period(sum(seconds(lubridate::hms(time)))), 
         .by = category) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = subcat, 
              values_from = time,
              names_prefix = "time_",
              values_fn = lubridate::hms) %>%
  select(order(colnames(.))) # cosmetic, just to reorder column names

Output:
#   category time_2   time_3    time_4    total    
#   <chr>    <Period> <Period>  <Period>  <Period> 
# 1 A        1H 0M 0S NA        2H 30M 0S 3H 30M 0S
# 2 B        NA       1H 30M 0S 30M 0S    2H 0M 0S 
# 3 C        NA       1H 0M 0S  NA        1H 0M 0S 

Data:
data <- read.table(text = "category subcat  time
A   2   01:00:00
B   4   00:30:00
A   4   02:30:00
B   3   01:30:00
C   3   01:00:00", h = TRUE)

Note that you included sample data in two formats. The above will work if your data are formatted like the table you presented. If your data look like the sample data df provided, then try:
df <- data.frame(category = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "B"),
                 subcat = c(2, 4, 4, 3, 3),
                 time = c(1, 0.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1))

df %>% 
  mutate(time = seconds_to_period(seconds(time * 60 * 60))) %>%
  mutate(total = seconds_to_period(sum(seconds(time))), 
         .by = category) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = subcat, 
              values_from = time,
              names_prefix = "time_") %>%
  select(order(colnames(.)))

#   category time_2   time_3    time_4    total    
#   <chr>    <Period> <Period>  <Period>  <Period> 
# 1 A        1H 0M 0S NA        2H 30M 0S 3H 30M 0S
# 2 B        NA       1H 30M 0S 30M 0S    2H 0M 0S 
# 3 C        NA       1H 0M 0S  NA        1H 0M 0S 


This has worked beautifully with the example data and not with my actual data. I suspect an issue is that all my other variables are messing with it, because it's given me a results table exactly as long as my dataset. Do you have any idea why, or how to fix it? (I'm working on building a more coherent example data, but I'm still ot sure how to 'give' ti to the questions interface.) I appreciate your help, and will contnue to work on it

@user25005226 try using dput - for instance, to provide the first 15 rows of data for your_data, you could edit your question to include the output of dput(your_data[1:15,]) (it starts with structure(…)

Limey pointed you in the right direction. The pivot_longer function is a tricky one to wrap your head around, but it is quite powerful. I'd suggest try some of the examples in the documentation (also in this vignette: Pivoting)
Using the data you've provided,
df <- data.frame(cat = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "B"), subcat= c(2, 4, 4, 3, 3), time= c(1, 0.5,2.5,1.5,1))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(time = as.period(time))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(sectime = period_to_seconds(time))

df |>
  group_by(cat, subcat) |> 
  summarize(time = seconds_to_period(sum(time))) |> 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols      = cat,     # rows in the new table
    names_prefix = "time_", # this is combined with the below line, i.e. "time_3"
    names_from   = subcat,  # indicates a new column for each subcategory
    values_from  = time     # the column of data
  ) |> 
  mutate(
    total = sum(c_across(starts_with("time")), na.rm = TRUE) |> 
      seconds_to_period()
  )

#`summarise()` has grouped output by 'cat'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
## A tibble: 3 × 5
## Groups:   cat [3]
#  cat   time_2   time_4   time_3   total   
#  <chr> <Period> <Period> <Period> <Period>
#1 A     1S       2.5S     NA       3.5S    
#2 B     NA       0.5S     1S       1.5S    
#3 C     NA       NA       1.5S     1.5S  

The mutate statement at the end adds the total column. It looks over all columns (c_across) whose names begin with (starts_with) "time" and sums each row. It removes missing values as it would otherwise have an undefined sum in some cases.
Note: The order of the pivoted columns depends on the order they appear in the data if my understanding is correct. Which is why time_4 appears before time_3.

df %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = "category",
    names_from = "subcat",
    values_from = "time"
  ) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    total = sum(
      c_across(
        c(`2`, `3`, `4`)
        ), 
      na.rm = T
      )
    ) %>%
  ungroup()


Thank you! I really appreciate your help! Two quick questions: would this work with a lot more subcategories, is there  a way to automate the sum calculation without having to list every column?

And do you know if this works with time data?

You may have to use lubridate functions to handle the time data formatting, but pivot() functions work with any variable types. And yes, instead of c(...), use a select() helper function like starts_with() or matches()
